# Where can I find a graph test suite?

Tags: algorithm, testing, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Lately, I've started experimenting with graphs, mainly for the entertainment value. Wikipedia is full of information on graphs, and I try to learn the theory while implementing some of the algorithms I find there (shortest path, DFS etc). I also try to make routines to classify graphs (tree, cyclic, planar etc), detect certain properties(clicques, leafs etc) and so forth. Great fun, although quite nerdy.

As my library grows, I find myself spending way too much time constructing graphs to test my code. If I want to test my `TGraph.IsTree` method, I need to construct some graphs that *are* trees, and some that *aren't* trees. I could generate graphs randomly, but then I wouldn't know what my method *should* return.

So my question is: Does anyone know of a test suite for graph programming? What I'm looking for is a collection of graphs in some well defined format, where there's also some information about the graph (classification, maximal clique, shortest path between some vertices etc.)

I know this exists for chess programs and the like, but I haven't been able to find something similar for graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Knuth's [Stanford Graph Base](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/sgb.html). This is a great collection of algorithms and datasets to test many different properties of graphs. You can download everything, all the docs and the source code in literate programming style. Something to really check out.

Answer (score 1):

[SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/) has a big list , Also for euclidean graphs you can use [CloudMade](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/). There are some other libraries (what other library I know is not suitable for your purposes) but I think these are enough for your test cases.